# disable scrolling forward in pageview

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to disable scrolling forward in pageview when the user reaches a specific page.

```
physics: controller.isLastPage()
                        ? NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()
                        : ScrollPhysics(),
```

this is what i have tried, but it doesn't work as I want since this solution disables scrolling in both directions.

Comment: You mean you don't want the pageview to loop back to the first item or do you want to hide that glow after the last item?

Comment: no, suppose that I have 5 pages, all of them are scrollable but I want to prevent the user from scrolling forward in page 4, i want him to be able to scroll backward only, and scroll forward using a button only (which i know how to do it)